# Loop while sending notification using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I've been struggle this for a long time and i really have no idea why this happens.

I'm using Cloud functions to send notification base on change in status. this is my code :

```
exports.sample = functions.database.ref('users/{pushID}/status').onUpdate(Snap => {
    const key = Snap.params.pushID;

    var ref = admin.database().ref('users');
    return ref.child(`${key}`).on("value", function(snap) {

        const category = snap.child('category').val();
        console.log("category",category);

        var ref = admin.database().ref('/categories/')
                return ref.child(`${category}`).on("value", function(snapshot){

                    const tokenID = snapshot.child('tokenID').val();
                    const payload = {
                        data: {
                          title: 'HELLO',
                          text: `HOW ARE YOU ?`
                        }
                      };

                      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenID, payload);


    })

});
```

After i deploy the function i change the status using the dashboard.

When i do this i get notification! (and i get "sent" on the log)
but when i change the "status" again, i get two notifications! and now i got two times "sent" on the log and so on.

It seems like a loop but i don't understand why,
whatever i log i get only one value, i don't get multiple tokens or anything, it just sends the same notification to the same user.

Whenever i re-deploy the function the "counter" resets and then the first change send only one notification.

my database looks like this :

```
users
-->push id
---->status=""
---->category="test"

categories
-->test
```

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because it's not indented at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson and now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listeners should be attached using [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) instead of on().  `on()` leaves the listener attached.

Comment: My problem was that i tried to change the first "on" to "once" and it didn't worked so i changed it back and didn't try to change them both to once. Thank you